# Multiple client and server in python without threading

Tags: python-3.x, client-server

I need to create a multiple client server program where one client will send data to server and the server will send it to other client.And i can not use Thread. I am passing the client IP and the client id as command line argument to specify the client in Ubuntu. But I can not understand how to bind with two client addresses. Here is the code below which I have tried.

client.py:

```
import socket
import sys

from scapy.all import *

host = sys.argv[1]
port = 5000
id = sys.argv[2]

def Main():
    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #mySocket.bind((host, port))
    mySocket.connect((host, port))


    p = IP(dst="127.0.0.1") / TCP(flags="S", sport=RandShort(), dport=80) / Raw("Hallo world!")


    for i in range(1):

        if id == 1:
            recvData = mySocket.recv(1024)
            print(recvData.decode())

        else:
            mySocket.send(bytes(p))
            print("Packet sent")

    mySocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Server.py:

```
import socket
from scapy.all import *

def Main():
    host = '192.168.1.0'
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mySocket.bind((host, port))
    mySocket.listen(5)


    for i in range(2):

        conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            break
        print("from connected  user: " + str(data))
        serverData = "reply from server"
        conn.send(serverData.encode())


    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? BTW, your `server.py` code looks like either bad copy and paste or like you've never run it before.

Comment: The problem is I can start the first client by giving its IP and ID. How can the server get that host IP from the client.py file? the host variable will be assigned by me when I start the client. And it is different for two different clients. How can the host variable in server.py file will get two different values for host and bind accordingly?

Comment: Why can't you use `threading`? It is a standard Python tool. Without it your server gonna be very limited and rigid transmitter.

Comment: @Poolka This is a task give by my teacher and he asked me not to use threading. I know with threading its easier and I did it already

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the point of the limitations you've described in the question. Anyway you can do what you want with the following simple codes for server and clients. Be aware **the implementation is very poor and highly inflexible**. However it does not use `threading`. To run it - start `server` (transmitter), then `client_0` (receiver), then `client_1` (sender).

server:

```
import socket


def main(ip, port):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.bind((ip, port))

        clients = list()
        for idx in range(2):
            sock.listen()
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            clients.append(conn)
            print('client_{} connected: {}'.format(idx, addr))

        data = b''
        while True:
            data_piece = clients[1].recv(1024)
            if not data_piece:
                break
            data += data_piece

        print(
            'Received [{}] from client_1. Sending to client_0...'
            .format(data.decode('UTF-8')))

        clients[0].send(data)

    print('stopped')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main('127.0.0.1', 5005)
```

client_0:

```
import socket


def main(ip, port):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))

        data = b''
        while True:
            data_piece = sock.recv(1024)
            if not data_piece:
                break
            data += data_piece

        print(
            'Received [{}] from server.'
            .format(data.decode('UTF-8')))

    print('stopped')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main('127.0.0.1', 5005)
```

client_1:

```
import socket


def main(ip, port):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        print('Sending to server...')
        sock.send('hello, world!'.encode('UTF-8'))

    print('stopped')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main('127.0.0.1', 5005)
```